# printing partitioned set in partition prob

Tags: java, algorithm

In  [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Example) I have understood the pseudo polynomial time algorithm.But i am not able to print the balanced set .

I am not able to figure out what to store instead of boolean values in the table constructed from algo.

Please provide algo to print partitioned subset also.

Can you provide solution in which I can modify table constructed to achieve the partitioned values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving partition problem is basically based on the formulas:

```
D(i,0) = true
D(0,x) = false if x!=0
D(i,x) = D(i-1,x-arr[i]) OR D(i-1,x)
```

In order to reproduce the actual element you can store another matrix, that will indicated if the element was taken or not, let this matrix be `Q`.

In other words, `Q(i,x) = true` if and only if `D(i-1,x-arr[i]) = true`.

Now, you can reproduce the set with:

```
set1 = {}
set2 = {}
x = SUM/2
for i from n to 0 decreasing:
   if Q(i,x):
      x = x - arr[i]
      set1.add(arr[i])
   else:
      set2.add(arr[i])
```

---

An alternative does not require constructing a second matrix `Q`, and instead retraces your steps. The basic idea is very similar to the previous one.

```
set1 = {}
set2 = {}
x = SUM/2
for i from n to 0 decreasing:
   if D(i-1,x-arr[i]): 
//   ^^ The condition was changed ^^
      x = x - arr[i]
      set1.add(arr[i])
   else:
      set2.add(arr[i])
```

The idea is similar, if by adding the element you get a valid solution, add it to `set`, it's part of the partition. Otherwise, it's not a part of the partition.

Comment: Can you provide solution in which I can modify table constructed to achieve the partitioned values.

Comment: @T.J. Look at my edit, it is possible to do it without creating a second `Q` matrix, and retracing your steps using the original `D` matrix.